# Unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'function' and 'int' error

Tags: python, function, for-loop

my code:

```
def start_input():
    start = int(input("\nAt what number shall we start, master? "))
    return start

def finish_input():
    end = int(input("\nwhen shall i finish, master? "))
    return end

def step_input():
    rise = int(input("\nby what ammount shall your numbers rise, master? "))
    return rise

def universal_step():
    rise = 3
    return rise

def the_counting():
    print("your desired count: ")
    for i in range ( start_input, finish_input +1, step_input): #can be also changed for automated step
        return print(i, finish_input ="  ")

def main():
    start_input()
    finish_input()
    step_input() #This can be changed for the universal_step function for no input if wanted
    the_counting()

main()

input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```

so without putting the code into cunks of functions it used to be fully functional, now all i get is a "Unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'function' and 'int' error" which is in the def counting function. im new to python and dont know why and whats happening. Thanks for any help :)

Comment: You probably want to call that function, using `()`.

Comment: Your issue is in your `the_counting()` function. You try to add `finish_input` and `1`, even though `1` is an int and `finish_input` is a function. You can't add a function to a number. You probably meant to call your function with `finish_input()`

Comment: The issue that immediately sticks out to me is 

for i in range ( start_input, finish_input +1

Basically, you're trying to add an integer to a function, which is not a valid operation. A function is a methodology to do something. An integer is, well, an integer.

Comment: You're also `return`ing a `print()`, do one or the other, or print _then_ return

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the things you're using in your `range` are functions, not variables; you have to call (add call parens) them to get their value, changing:

```
for i in range ( start_input, finish_input +1, universal_step):
```

to (with [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) spacing):

```
for i in range(start_input(), finish_input() + 1, universal_step()):
```